# Check if string contains only whitespace

Tags: python, text, whitespace

How can I test if a string contains only whitespace?

Example strings:

- `"   "` (space, space, space)
- `" \t \n "` (space, tab, space, newline, space)
- `"\n\n\n\t\n"` (newline, newline, newline, tab, newline)

Comment: Is newline a whitespace? Tab should be one to many whitespaces.

Answer (score 421, accepted):

Use the [`str.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) method:

> Return `True` if there are only whitespace characters in the string and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise.
>
> A character is whitespace if in the Unicode character database (see [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata)), either its general category is Zs (“Separator, space”), or its bidirectional class is one of WS, B, or S.

Combine that with a special case for handling the empty string.

Alternatively, you could use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and check if the result is empty.

Comment: This fails in Python 2.4 if string contains a non-breaking space, charcode `U+00A0` or `ALT+160`.  Looks fixed in Python 2.7, however.

Comment: Keep in mind that this does not check for `None`, or `''`

Comment: In python 2.7.13, isspace() will consider non-breaking space as a space. Nice!

Comment: You might also want to exclude empty strings as well, in that case you can do: `if len(str) == 0 or str.isspace():`

Comment: @Joe `len(my_str) == 0` can also be written `not my_str`.

Comment: `"".isspace()` returning `False` is a pretty huge WTF.

Comment: That isn’t a white space character, that’s literally nothing. It doesn’t check for None or “”

Answer (score 78):

[str.isspace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) returns `False` for a valid and empty string

```py
>>> tests = ['foo', ' ', '\r\n\t', '']
>>> print([s.isspace() for s in tests])
[False, True, True, False]
```

Therefore, checking with `not` will also evaluate `None` Type and `''` or `""` (empty string)

```py
>>> tests = ['foo', ' ', '\r\n\t', '', None, ""]
>>> print ([not s or s.isspace() for s in tests])
[False, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Comment: Why the choice to have it return `True` for `None` ?

Answer (score 39):

You want to use the [`isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) method

> str.**isspace()**
>
> Return true if there are only whitespace characters in the string and
>   there is at least one character, false otherwise.

That's defined on every string object. Here it is an usage example for your specific use case:

```
if aStr and (not aStr.isspace()):
    print aStr
```

Comment: Is this not the same solution as the current [top and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405300/11301900) ?

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [`str.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) method.

Answer (score 15):

for those who expect a behaviour like the apache [StringUtils.isBlank](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)) or Guava [Strings.isNullOrEmpty](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty(java.lang.String)) :

```
if mystring and mystring.strip():
    print "not blank string"
else:
    print "blank string"
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the length of the list given by of split() method.

```
if len(your_string.split()==0:
     print("yes")
```

Or
Compare output of strip() method with null.

```
if your_string.strip() == '':
     print("yes")
```

Comment: There is no reason to split the string, `len()` works on strings. Also, the OP wasn't asking to test for the empty string, but for a string that was all spaces. Your second method isn't bad though.

Also, your parens surrounding the conditional aren't needed in python.

Comment: Strangely enough, the first method is actually a good way to check than *none* of the characters are spaces, if you replace `==0` with `==1`

Comment: `if len(your_string.split())==0:` --> `if not your_string.split():`, `if your_string.strip() == '':` --> `if not your_string.strip():`. In any case, the first is inferior to the existing solutions, and the second has already been mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that should work in all cases:

```
def is_empty(s):
    "Check whether a string is empty"
    return not s or not s.strip()
```

If the variable is None, it will stop at `not s`and not evaluate further (since `not None == True`). Apparently, the `strip()`method takes care of the usual cases of tab, newline, etc.

Comment: _since `not None == True`_ It's probably clearer to just say `None is False`. Also, `==` shouldn't be used for these comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

Resemblence with c# string static method isNullOrWhiteSpace.

```
def isNullOrWhiteSpace(str):
  """Indicates whether the specified string is null or empty string.
     Returns: True if the str parameter is null, an empty string ("") or contains 
     whitespace. Returns false otherwise."""
  if (str is None) or (str == "") or (str.isspace()):
    return True
  return False

isNullOrWhiteSpace(None) -> True // None equals null in c#, java, php
isNullOrWhiteSpace("")   -> True
isNullOrWhiteSpace(" ")  -> True
```

Comment: You can just `return (str is None) or (str == "") or (str.isspace())`

Comment: Oh, and both `None` and `""` are falsy, so you can just: `return not str or  str.isspace()`

Comment: @AMC could you elaborate  this, I dont understand what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming in your scenario, an empty string is a string that is truly empty or one that contains all white space.

```
if(str.strip()):
    print("string is not empty")
else:
    print("string is empty")
```

Note this does not check for `None`

Comment: Hasn't this already been covered by existing answers?

Answer (score 2):

I used following:

```
if str and not str.isspace():
  print('not null and not empty nor whitespace')
else:
  print('null or empty or whitespace')
```

Comment: _null_ Do you mean `None` ?

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string is just a spaces or newline

Use this simple code

```
mystr = "      \n  \r  \t   "
if not mystr.strip(): # The String Is Only Spaces!
    print("\n[!] Invalid String !!!")
    exit(1)
mystr = mystr.strip()
print("\n[*] Your String Is: "+mystr)
```