# First true value if statement

Tags: python

I am looping through the lines of a text document, trying to find the first blank line that occurs after another line (say line 100 for this example).

My code is:

```
BlankLines=[]
f=open(MyFile, 'r')
for num, line in enumerate(f):
    if line=='\n' and num>100:
        BlankLines.append(num)
Result=Blanklines[0]
```

There are multiple lines that meet this criteria, but I just want the first line that meets it. What is the most elegant way of doing this? Is there a way to do it without creating a list and then selecting the first element?

Thanks!

Comment: [Very relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/how-to-check-if-text-is-empty-spaces-tabs-newlines-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for `break` of `for`-loops:

```
f=open(MyFile, 'r')
for num, line in enumerate(f):
    if line=='\n' and num>100:
        break
else:
    num = None
Result = num
```

Comment: All loops! Also while.

Comment: +1. It can easily be adapted to the necessary definition of a blank line (`re.match("\s*$", line)` instead of `line=='\n'`, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes the first line is numbered 0. (code not tested) First loop skips lines you don't want to check.

```
n = 100
f = open(MyFile, 'r')
for _ in xrange(n): # n is first line to check for blank, skip previous lines
    next(f)
for line in f: # reading the file continues where you left off
    line = line.strip() # allows for lines that have spaces and tabs
    if len(line) == 0:
        return n # returns line number
    n += 1
f.close()
```

If you only care about lines with just \n, leave out the strip() and use

```
    if line == '\n':
```

as in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a keyword called "break" and it exits from loops. Use it when the first line has been found.

However, as user @wnnmaw pointed out, comparing to "\n" might not cut it in all situations. What if the line is a lot of spaces? Should it be considered empty then too?

If you think so, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/how-to-check-if-text-is-empty-spaces-tabs-newlines-in-python).