# default dict counts for spaces in python

Tags: python, dictionary

why does default dict count for the number of empty spaces in my list?

I calculate the number of times a character appears in a word using default dict. But My code also counts the number of empty spaces between the words aswell. So how do I calculate only the occurence of words and omit the empty spaces that occur in my words.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count_var(word):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for val in word:
        d[val]+=1
    return d

ct = count_var('big data examiner')


print ct

defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 3, ' ': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'i': 2, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'x': 1})
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? And why don't you just use `collections.Counter`?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you replicate the same code using counter?

Comment: Why not [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), try it, and see? But bear in mind that people rarely ask questions like that when the answer is *"because you can't use [whatever] to do this"*...

Comment: @jonrsharpe but even counter counts the empty spaces.

Comment: @dangerous oh for pity's... `Counter` **just simplifies your code**. If you want it to count *words*, rather than *characters* (including spaces), you have to pass it **words rather than characters**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I hope this isnt a stupid question. I couldnt find the answer by surfing google. thats why I posted it here. ok I will keep this in mind while I post next time.

Comment: You can find [whether your character, or string, is whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/how-to-check-if-text-is-empty-spaces-tabs-newlines-in-python) by saying `val.isspace()`. Then you can choose whether to add it to your count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question:

> why does default dict count for the number of empty spaces in my list?

Because **the spaces are still characters**. For example:

```
>>> list('big data examiner')
['b', 'i', 'g', ' ', 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', ' ', 'e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'r']
               # ^                        ^
```

As currently written, your code counts every character, *including spaces*. If you want to exclude spaces from the count, you need to **make that explicit**:

```
def count_var(word):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for val in word:
        if val != ' ':  # exclude spaces
            d[val]+=1
    return d
```

Alternatively, rather than excluding `' '` from the counting process, simply **don't use that key** in whatever you do with `d` next.

---

Note that `collections` also provides [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which can significantly simplify your code:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(char for char in 'big data examiner' if char != ' ')
Counter({'a': 3, 'e': 2, 'i': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'x': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

```
ct = count_var('big data examiner')
```

To

```
ct = count_var('big data examiner'.split())
```

This will count words instead of characters. And to answer why it was counting spaces, because spaces are a valid character, just like any letter or digit would be, so it gets counted.

Also note that there exists `collections.Counter` that is better suited to tackle this problem for you, especially since you are already importing from `collections`.

**Edit**

Regarding how to use `collections.Counter` the same idea applies from above.

This counts **characters**

```
>>> Counter('big data examiner')
Counter({'a': 3, 'i': 2, 'e': 2, ' ': 2, 't': 1, 'b': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'm': 1, 'g': 1, 'x': 1, 'r': 1})
```

This counts **words**

```
>>> Counter('big data examiner'.split())
Counter({'big': 1, 'data': 1, 'examiner': 1})
```

**Edit #2** Counting all non-space characters

You can use `str.replace(' ', '')`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('big data examiner'.replace(' ', ''))
Counter({'a': 3, 'i': 2, 'e': 2, 'x': 1, 'b': 1, 'r': 1, 'g': 1, 'n': 1, 't': 1, 'm': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Comment: what does split do here?

Comment: @dangerous what it always does: [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)!

Comment: @dangerous [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will parse a string into a list of tokens based on the provided delimiter. If no delimiter is provided, it will split on white space.

Comment: @Cyber I want my output like this , I dont want words, I just need characters excluding that empty spaces. Counter({'a': 3, 'i': 2, 'e': 2, 't': 1, 'b': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'm': 1, 'g': 1, 'x': 1, 'r': 1})

Comment: @dangerous why don't you just ignore the spaces in whatever you use it for next?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - ok then I will ignore the spaces then, was curious on how to do that in python.

Comment: @dangerous Edited again.