# Python global variable isspace() error

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I define a global of sshIP along with others in `Main`

```
 foo,bar,sshIP = '','',''
```

using wx button event I define a function called `load` to test to see if sshIP has a value or if it is still '', from what I've seen I can do this with isspace(), however my implementation seems to always be met with a NameError that sshIP is not defined. `load` is a function of `Main`

```
def load(self,e):
    if sshIP.isspace(): 
        self.progressBox.AppendText("Cannot install, device not connected")
    else:
        self.installBtn.Enable()
```

Comment: Those are empty strings not whitespace characters

Comment: the answer here by John Machin shows that isspace() should result in False (becasue of the not) for `' ', None, /t, ''`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/how-to-check-if-text-is-empty-spaces-tabs-newlines-in-python

Comment: `''.isspace()` returns `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Main` is a function, those variables are not global unless you have marked them as such.

```
def Main():
    global foo
    global bar
    global sshIP

    foo,bar,sshIP = '','',''
```

But you might consider passing these variables as parameters to whatever you call next, rather than using globals.

To test for a non-empty string you can just:

```
if sshIP:
```

since an empty string is False in a boolean context.

Comment: perfect, thank you. 
`global sshIP, foo,bar`
`sshIP, foo,bar = '','',''`