# How do I check if a string contains no characters?

Tags: python

I know this is a similar post to [How to check if text is "empty" (spaces, tabs, newlines) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/how-to-check-if-text-is-empty-spaces-tabs-newlines-in-python)
, however I'm still having troubles.

I don't understand how to use it, I'm trying to check if a variable, which contains a string, consists of only spaces, tabs and newlines. How would I use issppace() as I'm confused with it always being False?.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show some actual code, what you expect, and what you get, otherwise we can only guess

Comment: have you tried using string.strip and seeing if that's empty

Comment: My guess: " I'm trying to check if a variable, which contains a string" you have something like a list of strings and you want to check if any/all of them are empty/whitespace

Comment: Are you sure that the string "only consists of space, tab and newline"? There might be other non-printable characters in the string, like `\x00`, that are not spaces. What does `repr(your_string)` or `[ord(c) for c in your_string]` print? You could also use `[(c, c.isspace()) for c in your_string]` to find the culprit.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: @Chris_Rands yeah you are correct

Comment: For now, since we can't tell what your actually problem is until add an [mcve] to your question, I'm closing it as a duplicate @ProTechXS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
if string_to_check.strip():
    print("Contains characters")
else:
    print("Contains no characters")
```

Comment: Understood, cheers mate