# How to extract the index of an empty excel cell?

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a python script that cleans and order the data of a csv file , the script works fine but one problem remains which is to verify if the cell is empty or contains just a space like " "

this the condition that i've tried but it didn't work

k is a list

```py
if k[i][j] is "  " or k[i][j] is None  :

            print('this cell is empty ',k.index(k[i][j]))
```

i expected that the condition will return the index of the cell but it didn't 
I'm wodering how to fix this problem ?
thank you in advance

Comment: k is the 2 d array that contains the data from the excel table? Surely the index would then be `(i,j)`?

Comment: replace `k.index(k[i][j])` with `[i,j]`

Comment: @nick yes the index was (i,j) thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement suggestion: for space checking a more robust solution could  be the function [`str.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace), because this function also considers newlines, tabs and other unicode space characters. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/how-to-check-if-text-is-empty-spaces-tabs-newlines-in-python).

So your code could look like this (first checking for `None` and then calling a function):

```
if k[i][j] is None or k[i][j].isspace():
    ...
```

---

Then, to get the index, your code would suggest that `i` and `j` already are the coordinates of the cell. Am I understanding your code wrong?

You could just print those variables then:

```
print('this cell is empty ', i, j)
```

Does that solve your issue?